# How do I prevent drag on a child, but allow drag on the parent?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have a div which the user can drag, inside that div is a span with some text which I want to allow the user to select (thus they cannot drag it). How do I allow the div to drag, but not the span?

The dragstart event is on the div.

I'm probably overlooking something simple. I tried draggable=true on the div, and draggable=false on the span. That didn't work. Tried returning false on dragstart, that didn't work either.

dragstart (roughly):

```
var jTarget = $(e.target);
if ((jTarget.is('div.header') || (jTarget.parents('div.header')) 
       && !jTarget.is('a, input, span'))) 
{
   e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text", "test");
}
else
{
   if(e.preventBubble)
      e.preventBubble();
   if(e.stopPropagation)
      e.stopPropagation();
   return false;//???
}
```

The if else portion works as I expect, but I cannot get anything to stop the drag and allow the select.

Comment: Don't think it's possible - though you could work around it by providing a drag handle in the div that the drag events can be attached to, leaving the inner text to be selectable. There's no way to differentiate between a click/drag to move and a click/drag to highlight. They're both just a mouse-down followed by a mouse-move.

Comment: What code do you have in your `dragstart` handler?  Please add it to your question.

Comment: @Marc B - I was starting to think I might have to do that. It would be less than optimal though, as my span might take up 1.5 lines, and I want that other 0.5 line to be draggable. That would be rather difficult to pull off. And, this object is the header object, so adding another header for dragging purposes is out of the question.

Answer (score 43):

If you want to truly cancel out the drag and make it unnoticeable to parent drag handlers, you need to both `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`:

```
<div draggable="true" ondragstart="console.log('dragging')">
    <span>Drag me! :)</span>
    <input draggable="true"
           ondragstart="event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();"
           value="Don't drag me :(">
</div>
```

Without the `stopPropagation`, the parent `ondragstart` will still be called even if the default behavior will be prevented (`event.defaultPrevented == true`). If you have code in that handler that doesn't handle this case, you may see subtle bugs.

You can of course put the JavaScript above inside `element.addEventListener('dragstart', ...)` too.

Comment: Having `draggable="true"` on the `input` element that you don't want to be draggable is a subtle but critical aspect of this answer that at first looks counter-intuitive, but is essential to get the input's `ondragstart` event to fire.  I'm just calling it out b/c that's the piece I was missing that this answer helped me find and may be for someone else too.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the `<input>` to work correctly on iOS (or any touch devices) when the input has the `draggable="true"`. The focus outline shows and keyboard is popping up, but can't type anything. Any workarounds? https://jsfiddle.net/yjk8uhwr/

Comment: Note that this does not work in Firefox - cannot select text in the input with the mouse

Comment: Since this answer uses `event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();` on the drag event, it never raises any touch scrolling events. Therefore, this breaks touch scrolling.

Answer (score 18):

just posting in case someone searches for it with a similar Problem

```
element.addEventListener('mousedown', function() { this.parentNode.setAttribute("draggable", false); });
element.addEventListener('mouseup', function() { this.parentNode.setAttribute("draggable", true); });
```

worked for me

Comment: A nice and simple solution. It worked better for me with "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" events, tough.

Comment: Interesting, for me actually the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` works and `mousedown` / `mouseup` not. With those, I still couldn't select text in my nested `input`. Anyway, great idea @mech!

Comment: Building on @icl7126 comment, do the same thing with `ontouchstart` and `ontouchend` for mobile support.

Comment: When the first parent is not the `draggable` container use `.closest` to get the first parent with the `draggable` attribute like so `this.closest('[draggable]')`

Answer (score 6):

You can change the child element to draggable and prevent default when ondragstart, this will leave the regular behavior on the child element and the parent will still be draggable

```
function drag(e){ if(e.target.type=="range")e.preventDefault();/*rest of your code*/  }
```

html:

```
<input type="range" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
```

Comment: Works for me ! And seems to be the 'cleanest' solution, in contrast to a mousedown handler, which imo has nothing to do with drag events to begin with. As an addition to this solution, I use a seperate function to cancel drag for any child element(s), so the actual drag function doesn't get cluttered with conditions and what not ! Can call it dragCancel or something ;)

Answer (score 3):

Put a mousedown handler on the span and stop the event propagation there.

Comment: tested (i have a similar Problem), at least it works that no dragging will happen, but anything else won't happen either, no selection of text possible, and if the object is contenteditable you can not set the Cursor ...

Comment: Works for me for input and textarea elements as a child with `event.stopPropogation` onMouseDown

Answer (score 1):

In my application, I was unable to get any of the other solutions listed here to work.  This is what worked for me:

```
ondragstart="event.preventDefault();" draggable="false"
```

In my specific case, it was a text input inside a div.

Comment: event.preventDefault(); has no effect with the setting draggable="false"; To engage event.preventDefault(); you need to set draggable="true". Otherwise there no reason to include that line in your element.

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired by a few of the answers here and I think I came up with the cleanest and most reusable solution. I use a mouse down event to check if the element should be draggable or not. I do this by verifying if it has a specific class name that I only assign to draggable elements. On the mouse up event, I go through all of the elements with that class tag and set their draggable values back to true.

This can break if the input node is a deep child of the draggable div, but then you can use the same algorithm as in the mouse up event and set all of the values to false.

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
 var clickedElem = event.target;
    if(!clickedElem.classList.contains("drop_content")){
        clickedElem.parentElement.setAttribute("draggable",false);
    }
}, false);

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    var boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".drop_content");
    for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++){
        boxes[i].setAttribute("draggable",true);
    }
}, false);
```

```css
div{
  display:block;
  background: black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="drop_content" draggable="true">
      <input value="Can't drag me">
    </div>
    <div class="drop_content" draggable="true">
      <input value="Can't drag me either">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set a flag that indicates whether the mouse is on the child or not. this works for me very well.
if you set e.preventDefault() without condition,You will lose draggable parents.

html:

```
<div draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart()">
    <span onmouseenter="childMouseEnter()" onmouseleave="childMouseLeave()">Dont 
        Drag
    </span>        
</div>
```

javascript:

```
let mouseOnChild = false
function childMouseEnter(){
    mouseOnChild = true;
}
function childMouseLeave(){
    mouseOnChild = false;
}
function dragStart(e){
    if(!mouseOnChild){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    //other operations....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that storing a flag as data attribute is a reasonably acceptable workaround:

```
export function Draggable(props: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>) {
  return (
    <div
      {...props}
      draggable={true}
      onMouseDown={(event) => {
        props.onMouseDown?.(event);
        const handles = event.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('.drag-handle');
        const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
        const allow = [...handles].map(handle => handle.contains(target)).some(i => i);
        if (allow) {
          event.currentTarget.setAttribute('data-draggable', 'yes');
        } else {
          event.currentTarget.removeAttribute('data-draggable');
        }
      }}
      onDragStart={(event) => {
        props.onDragStart?.(event);
        const allow = event.currentTarget.hasAttribute('data-draggable');
        if (!allow) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
          return;
        }
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```