# Drag parent, but select text on child?

Tags: javascript, css, html, draggable

I want the parent div to be draggable, but text in the child span to be selectable:

```
<aside draggable="true" id="dragme">
    This is an aside, drag me. <span id="copyme" draggable="false">But copy me!</span>
</aside>
```

There is already a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848140/how-do-i-prevent-drag-on-a-child-but-allow-drag-on-the-parent), but jQuery is used there. In do not use jQuery, just html5.

I have tried to stop the event from dragging, but nothing happens unless I use preventDefault - and then I can't select either:

```
function dontdrag(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
    ev.stopImmadiatePropagation();
    return false;
}
```

There is a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/8NvAT/6/

Can anyone see a solution to this today?

UPDATE: There might be a solution, please see the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/8NvAT/7/

It behaves a bit strange, but it works. Can anyone make a solution that is better out of this new fiddle?

Comment: Try this: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop
The key is that you can make an evaluation in the ondragstart event, and stop the drag. Pretty sure. There might be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this same type of problem by using dedicated drag-handle areas. So instead of adding `draggable="true"` to some arbitrary parent, I put an absolutely-positioned drag handle square in one of the corners of the parent. This might not be the best solution for when you want to hide the draggable implementation (or just make it look better), but it certainly makes it easier for the drag events.

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listeners to the "copyme" element like this:

```
cm.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    dm.setAttribute("draggable", "false");
});
cm.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    var selObj = window.getSelection();
    if (selObj) {
        var selRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
        var ancestor = selRange.commonAncestorContainer;
        if (ancestor.parentNode === cm) {
            selObj.removeAllRanges();
        }
    }
    dm.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
});
```

For the full solution see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/8NvAT/12/

I think this is (in principle) the best you can do at the moment.