# Drag&Drop keep behavior of editable content

Tags: javascript, html

i'm experimenting with Drag&Drop in Javascript. So far it is working but my editable Content within the dragable objects aren't useable anymore (hence not the way they normally are)

this is an example of an dropable object:

```
<div id="ziel_2" draggable="true" trvdroptarget="true">
    <div> some text<br>some text</div>
    <div contenteditable="true">some text</div>
</div>
```

the whole object shouldn't be dragged if i try to use the contenteditable div, i want to click in the text and edit it or just select some text in it ang drag it just like normal

so the question: how can i cancel the drag-event if e.target.hasAttribute("contenteditable") in ondragstart?

EDIT: this is the Code behind the Scenes so far:

```
function lieferungen_draggable_add_dragstart(obj)
{
    obj.addEventListener('dragstart', function (e) {
      if(e.target.hasAttribute("contenteditable")) { /* make something stop this thing */ }
      e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
      e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.getAttribute('id'));
        return false;
    });
    return obj;
}
```

EDIT2:

```
contenteditableDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', function() { this.parentNode.setAttribute("draggable", false); });
contenteditableDiv.addEventListener('mouseup', function() { this.parentNode.setAttribute("draggable", true); });
```

this worked for me based on an idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9339176/4232410

thanks for your help!

Comment: You could give an id to the contenteditable section, then when binding draggable events, exclude that/those ID(s) - need to see your code really

Comment: added the Code, but i don't know how to exclude specific Elements within the draggable element

Comment: just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848140/how-do-i-prevent-drag-on-a-child-but-allow-drag-on-the-parent that seems to be a similar question, but with no results either ;(

Comment: see edit, it works ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check for the contentEditable status of the element and any parent elements (see [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable) for info about the attribute)

```
for (var el = e.target; el && el !== el.parentNode; el = el.parentNode) {
   if (el.contentEditable === "true") {
      return false;
   }
}
// Continue processing here
```

Comment: You can also check for "false" and break early - but this gives the basic idea ;-)

Comment: just found out, that e.target alway Returns the outer div, not the object i clicked with my mouse ... how to find out?

Comment: but even if i return false in the first line of dragstart, nothing changes, object is still draggable ;(

Comment: contenteditableDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', function() { if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation(); }); will prevent dragging, but also interacting with the object like selecting text or Setting the Cursor ;(

Comment: "this" is the element clicked, "e.target" is the one with the listener on it - my bad for forgetting that, glad you got it working though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(e.target.hasAttribute("contenteditable")) { return false; }
```

Basically, that's saying get out and don't do anything else if the target has attribute: `contenteditable`