# How to Stop Croppie Drag Behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, croppie

I have Croppie inside another element that is itself draggable.  I want to prevent Croppie's drag behaviour so that the outer element can be dragged (by mouse over Croppie) without Croppie dragging too.  Actually I need to turn this behaviour on and off.  I've tried all the usual permutations:

```
$(instance.data.newDiv0).on("click", function() {
    console.log("outermatte clicked");
    instance.triggerEvent('outerClicked'); // Triggers Bubble event to save new picture position
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Croppie is somewhat buried in my code.  It's wrapped in two divs:

```
instance.data.newDiv0 = $('<div class="outermatte" id=' + instance.data.outermatte + '><span class="BigNum"></span></div>');                          
    instance.canvas.append(instance.data.newDiv0);
    instance.data.newDiv1 = $('<div class="innermatte"  id=' + instance.data.innermatte + '></div>');
    instance.canvas.append(instance.data.newDiv1);
```

And dynamically written into those by:

```
var basic = $(instance.data.newDiv1).croppie({
    viewport: { width: (instance.data.canvas_width * properties.pic_mat_ratio / 100), height: (instance.data.canvas_height * properties.pic_mat_ratio / 100 * instance.data.frame_ratio) },
    boundary: { width: (instance.data.canvas_width * properties.pic_mat_ratio / 100), height: (instance.data.canvas_height * properties.pic_mat_ratio / 100 * instance.data.frame_ratio) },
    showZoomer: false,
    enableZoom: properties.enableZoom,
    enableResize: false, //properties.enableResize,
    enableOrientation: properties.enableOrientation,
    enforceBoundary: true,
    enableExif: true,
  customClass: "mycroppie",
    update: function (data) {  //when Croppie updates
    results = basic.croppie('get');
      if (results.points[2] > 0 || results.points[3] > 0) {
        instance.publishState("stateZoom", results.zoom);
        instance.publishState("stateTopLeftX", results.points[0]);
        instance.publishState("stateTopLeftY", results.points[1]);
        instance.publishState("stateBottomRightX", results.points[2]);
        instance.publishState("stateBottomRightY", results.points[3]);
        instance.triggerEvent("croppieChanged");
        console.log("CROPPIE CHANGED: " + " " + results.points[0] + " " + results.points[1] + " " + results.points[2] + " " + results.points[3] + " " + results.zoom);
      }
    }
});


basic.croppie('bind', {
    url: properties.image_url,
    points: [properties.topLeftX, properties.topLeftY, properties.bottomRightX, properties.bottomRightY],
    zoom: properties.zoom,
    orientation: properties.orientation
});
```

And all that is in a plugin inside Bubble.is.

But I can't get to Croppies event handlers without editing Croppie which I don't want to do.  I wish there was just an addition "enableDrag" option along with all the other enables.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Could you show a snippet of your code with the croppie instance and it's html container?

Comment: BTW, I still need to be able to capture a click on Croppie.

Comment: @silencedogood, just added that!

Comment: Hm. e.stopPropagation and e.preventDefault should solve this issue. Where are you calling these methods? Also, this may be helpful if you haven't already found it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848140/how-do-i-prevent-drag-on-a-child-but-allow-drag-on-the-parent

Comment: Hi Silence, I added to the first code snippet to show how I am using the stop/prevent stuff.  I've done the same with mouseup/down/drag events and anything else I could think of.  Thanks for the other thread link.  I had not found that one and it's pretty darn close to what I'm trying to do but I have no access to the draggable elements code (thats in Bubble.is) and no access to Croppies code.  I only get to play with the code in the middle which gives me a fair amount of control over the behaviour of Croppie but not over it's drag events it seems.

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you're not passing the event object to your callback function. Based on your code, I would expect it to read: $(instance.data.newDiv0).on("click", function(event) { .. }

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think your code gives the impression that it's executing properly because you're calling:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Which rests on the native event object. However, it isn't referencing your 'click' event.
If you change your code to:

```
$(instance.data.newDiv0).on("click", function(e) {
    console.log("outermatte clicked");
    instance.triggerEvent('outerClicked'); 
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

You should then get the desired behavior. If this doesn't work, I'm at a loss to be honest.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve it.  But I had not considered that there might be a difference between using event and passing e.  That lead me to read up and I am wiser now!  So, thank you :)

Comment: Well, I just found out it actually depends on the browser you're using. In most versions of FF, your code would error out because the event object isn't offered globally. In chrome and some others, it is offered as a global. I just learned this myself. Anyways, good luck!